# Preserve already minified code fragments in Google Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have some code, that I want to run through Google Closure Compiler.

The problem, however, is, that besides my own code, there is a fragment of already minified code, which I can't get the original sources for.

So when running this through the compiler, the minified code gets compiled again and thus completely messed up.

Anyone knows an annotation or another technique to prevent Google Closure Compiler from compiling certain parts of the code?

```
// my code
function someFunction() {
  // some code blabla
}

someFunction();

// already minified code; should be preserved in its state
!function(){window.a='abc'; /* ... */ }();
```

<sub>PS: I know, one solution would be to move the minified code to another file, but I was wondering, if there is another solution.</sub>

Comment: Excluding that section from the compilation is the only way I would know to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There two solutions people use:
1) concatenate the already compiled source after compilation. I've seen people use the compiler's "output wrapper" option for this.
2) wrap the code in an eval (or inject into the page using appending a script tag):

```
eval("my precompiled compiled code here");
```